# instance of bean with panelGrid

Tags: jsf-2

i use panelGrid to display my result, but i have a probleme i don't know how instance my class in panelGrid, i have problem with my list i can't add element i have error, i think that i need to instance my class but i don't know how, how can i add element in my list ?

this is my code :

```
@Component("points")
public class Points extends FormTemplate implements Serializable {

    private String taskId;
    private TaskInfo currentTask;
    private int taskNumber;
    Map<String,Object> varsMap;
    private ArrayList<RhReunionEntretin> pointsObjects;
    private ArrayList<RhReunionEntretin> removedPoints;
    private String loggedUser;



    @Override
    public void init() {

        if(varValues.get("points") != null)
            pointsObjects= (ArrayList<RhReunionEntretin>)varValues.get("points");
        else
            pointsObjects   = new ArrayList<RhReunionEntretin>();
        if(pointsObjects.size() == 0){
            List<Long> pointsMultiline = new ArrayList<Long>();
            if(varValues.get("form_1475754639065") != null) {
                pointsMultiline = (List<Long>) varValues.get("form_1475754639065");
                if (pointsMultiline != null && pointsMultiline.size() != 0) {
                    for (Long pr : pointsMultiline) {
                        RhReunionEntretin point = (RhReunionEntretin) businessService.getEntitytById("com.imaginepartners.imagineworkflow.models.rh.RhReunionEntretin", pr.toString());
                        pointsObjects.add(point);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        removedPoints   = new ArrayList<RhReunionEntretin>();

        loggedUser      = userService.getLoggedInUser().getId();
    }

    public void addPoint() {
        pointsObjects.add(new RhReunionEntretin());
    }
```

.xhtml

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

    #{taskController.registerTemplate('points','Points', fn:split('pointsObjects',',') )}






        <p:panelGrid style="margin-top:20px" id="compteRTemplate"  var="points" value="#{points.pointsObjects}" styleClass="entityList" >

        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column >Critères</p:column>
                <p:column >Evaluation</p:column>
                <p:column >Commentaire</p:column>
            </p:row>


        </f:facet>

        <p:row>

            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">Formation</p:column>

            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">
                <p:selectOneRadio id="formation"
                     value="#{points.pointsObjects.formation}">
                    <p:ajax event="blur"/>

                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="A" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="B" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="C" itemValue="C" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="NA" itemValue="NA" />
                </p:selectOneRadio></p:column>

            <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">
                <p:inputText
                              value="#{points.pointsObjects.commentaireForm}">

                </p:inputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
```

i get this error when i submit

```
oct. 25, 2018 10:50:52 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase execute
AVERTISSEMENT: For input string: "formation"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "formation"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:163)
    at javax.el.ListELResolver.getType(ListELResolver.java:71)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:215)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:84)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectOneValu
```

Comment: This appears to be the same issue answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32013318/4795356

Comment: And try to make an [mcve]. The error you get cannot be deduced from the code you posted!